# Is gpresult unreliable?

Tags: active-directory

Ok, in the interest of full disclosure, I despise the network admin at work and today I think the final straw got loaded on to the proverbial camel's back.

I have been working in the IT field for nearly 15 years and have always used gpresult to identify and diagnose active directory policy issues.  I have been engaged in a week long argument with our windows admin claiming that the GPO's are not applying to more than 400 machines we have.  My claim is based on the fact that when I run a gpresult on any machine every policy returns "not applied (reason unknown)".

His response is "gpresult is not accurate, you have a corrupt profile."

Personally, I think I have a corrupt admin.

I open the floor for discussion

Comment: You have a `corrupt admin` gpresult doesn't lie.

Comment: I have to agree with you on this one. His answer sounds like a blanket argument that people use when they have no clue as to what's going on or don't want to be bothered with finding out. Q: "Why is it like this?" A: "Umm, because I said so!". Did he offer to run gpresults? Did he give you any evidence to support his answer?

Comment: Nope, no back up.  He fails to realize that I probably do know more than he does, I've just been too wrapped up in the ERP implementation to get involved.  My running gpresult was my attempt at saying "look something is not right and I need you to sort it out."

Comment: Sounds like bs to me. I would ask him how to fix it and for him to do it and to watch him. Surely, if he can supply a simple answer, it must be simple to apply. If he doesn't allow you to watch, threaten to use metasploit to get a domain admin account. My response "hey if you don't want to do your job, I'll do it for you"...and be sure to smile :).

Comment: In an effort to "increase security" on our network, my personal domain admin account was taken away from me.  So doing it myself does add an extra layer of challenge.  I didn't have much else going on this weekend though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments above say it all. I've not once heard about anyone complaining about the reliability/credibility of gpresult. Your admin should get a new ego.

Comment: Voted as answer simply for "Your admin should get a new ego."  Had me in stitches.

Answer (score 2):

Having spent entirely too much of my life for the past three weeks banging my head on GPO/Profile issues (only on the admin side), I felt some fear reading this question. Happily, we have no ERP deployment going so I feel safe *whew*.

Yes. About that. In my particular case, gpresult is returning the correct list of policies but they're not actually doing what they're supposed to. Evidence in the event-logs suggests they're attempting to apply but failing. This is what *suggests* a bad profile (specifically a badly created Default User profile, as these are computer-lab stations for students).

When a station can't even figure out what GPOs it needs to apply, it's usually pretty noisy about it in the event-logs. I had that happen a month ago, and it turned out that the workstation in question had the NetBIOS TCP/IP Helper service disabled. Another one managed to pick the one Domain Controller it couldn't get to. Both were diagnosed through event-log reading and some network diagnostics on the machine in question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your admin sounds like he is deflecting.  I agree with everyone here.  To answer your specific question, gpresult does not include **local security policy**.  The RSOP MMC snap-in (`rsop.msc`) does include it since it is a nice fancy GUI, but I was disappointed when the HTML report did **not** include them.  That stuff can be kind of important, and it was to me at the time.  Made me look foolish when I was with a bunch of people and used it to "get the answer" when the employee in the know was out.  I was convinced he had not applied any secpol customizations.  FAIL!

To answer your GPO problem: are these GPO's linked from one OU to another? Our SOP is for our "domain admins," since we are a very large IT department, to link them from the OU where they create different GPOs based on their target audience and with the appropriately locked-down permissions for admin group (staff, students, special projects, etc.).  If you do not enable the linked GPO at the target OU level, it will obviously not apply.  If this guy does not know his stuff, this sounds like an obvious way to make the policy not apply.  Just right-click the linked OU at the target OU with `gpmc.msc` and click Enable (in case you are not familiar).  Hope that helps.